# Memory management error in my app

Tags: java, android, oop, media

I have made an android app in java works fine in the emulator but on a real phone it crashes it just give `out of memory error` my application has 63 pics, 10 audio songs, 4 video. The total size of my app is 141 MB how can i prevent this error from coming is it because i have too much data or is there a better way to store my Media in my apps.

Here are some images

1 Audio Gallery

video Gallery

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have had some trouble with my apps as well, particularly when I'm opening bitmaps. The amount of available memory decreases very quickly and you'll have to mark your bitmaps as disposed frequently (or use techniques to downgrade the resolution).

Comment: What are you trying to load everything in memory at once?

Comment: @NarendraPathai i just put it into a raw folder and linked so how can i manage to make it work

Comment: Only load what you need e.g. one or two at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in apps like images, sounds and videos is not recommended.. Similarly giving-away your app with songs, images and videos may lead you towards copyrights and piracy lawsuits.. But if you have data of your own then I suggest, you should implement Client/Server Architecture for your app.. Host items from server and retrieve them in your app when required..

Comment: but is there any other way

Comment: Well it's suggested to make app with as smaller size as possible.. Well if you still want to keep media items within your app resources then, you should load items in memory with care and precision as you'll never want to get OutOfMemoryException. Only load items when they are required. MediaPlayer handles songs and videos itself but as for images you'll have to be careful. Try to resize images according to screen sizes and load the resized bitmaps in memory (if required, else never)..

Answer (score 0):

Regaridng the memory that the device can hold,

Heap size depends on the hardware your running your app an. For example 16mb on a G1 and 32mb on a nexus one. Don't think there is much you can do about it. If you target versions below 3.0 that is.

As Google has indicated, all using this will do is tend to irritate users of your app. Your app will consume more memory and therefore will kick other apps out of memory more quickly. Some users will not like this behavior. And, it is very possible that this will only ever be a tablet option -- I would not assume that Ice Cream Sandwich phones will necessarily support android:largeHeap

I believe the memory gets initialized, once the resources has been loaded... Hope you are trying to load the resources in a activity that exceeds the heap memory in Android that's why you are getting Out of Memory.

Comment: Is it necessary to load all the images or media's on the same activity at once? Hoping you already has the compressed images... If not, you can compress the image in Adobe photoshop maintaining the same quality to some extent. 141 MB of resources is too huge on the device. It would be great, if you can explain what is your application about and what you are trying to acheive, so I can try to see alternate ways of loading the images or media...

Comment: well my app is an actress portfolio i have compressed all the media it came from 600MB to 141MB but still i cant play when i remove all the audio and video it works but it is important to keep all the media.

Comment: That's Ok. It does't mean you have to load all the image in a single shot. How many ImageViews or ImageButton do you have it in your activity. I think, you should use 5 or 6 controls and try to reuse them based on the context. If you don't mind, could you please attach a screenshot what you are trying to acheive, so I can think of a better solution...

Comment: Site is not allowing me to put pictures i require more reputation. and sorry for the late replay my pc was down